# Custom Excel formula went wrong

Tags: windows, excel, formula

I have a file in which I have a "created date" and a "request type" and a "due date" columns.

In the "due date" column I made this formula

```
=IF(OR(B2="PASSPORT LOST REPLACEMENT",B2="NATIONAL MDIFICATION"),A2+34,
```

The formula will add 34 days then print the result in cell c, but when I put the  "=" before the " IF " I get this error message:

> you have entered so many arguments for this function

Comment: Rather than having a long formula that's possibly difficult to maintain or debug why not set up a simple table with possible B2 texts in one column and then days to add for weekday in the next and weekend in the third, then you can use a simple INDEX/MATCH formula like `=INDEX(Table,MATCH(B2,rowlables,0),IF(WEEKDAY(A2,2)<6,2,3))+A2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the order of conditions is OK, you had one bracket misplaced - the last in this piece:

```
IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,WEEKDAY(A2)=1),A2+3,A2+5),
```

So the corrected result is:

```
=IF(OR(B2="PASSPORT LOST REPLACEMENT",B2="NATIONAL MDIFICATION"),A2+34,
   IF(OR(B2="OCCUPATION CHANGE"),A2+21,
       IF(OR(B2="IQAMA OF ISSUANCE",B2="IQAMAS RE-NEWAL",B2="LOST IQAMA REPLACEMENT",B2="TRANSFER OF SPONSORSHIP",B2="BUSINESS VISA R",B2="SEPARATION OF PERSONNEL"),A2+7,
            IF(OR(B2="LETTERS FROM SISTER COMPANIES",B2="NAME MODIFICATION", B2="MULTIPLE VISA",B2="ADD PERSONNEL"),IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,WEEKDAY(A2)=1),A2+3,A2+5),
                IF(OR(B2="LETTERS",B2="PRINT FROM JAWAZAT",B2="EXTENDED OF VISIT VISA",B2="INFORMATION MODIFICATION"),A2+1)))))
```

Comment: In addition there's a typo in `B2="NATIONAL MDIFICATION"` - please be aware.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is towards the end of your formula where you have 
`IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,WEEKDAY(A2)=1),A2+3, A2+5, IF(OR(B2="LETTERS",B2="PRINT FROM JAWAZAT",B2="EXTENDED OF VISIT VISA",B2="INFORMATION MODIFICATION"),A2+1)))`

Your if has three result conditions, namely `A2+3`, `A2+5` and `IF(OR(B2...`

There should only be two of these.

Comment: Im sorry  the previous is a mistake

IF(OR(B2="PASSPORT LOST REPLACEMENT",B2="NATIONAL MDIFICATION"),A2+34,)
IF(OR(B2="OCCUPATION CHANGE"),A2+21,
IF(OR(B2="IQAMA OF ISSUANCE",B2="IQAMAS RE-NEWAL",B2="LOST IQAMA REPLACEMENT",B2="TRANSFER OF SPONSORSHIP",B2="BUSINESS VISA R",B2="SEPARATION OF PERSONNEL"),A2+7,
IF(OR(B2="LETTERS FROM SISTER COMPANIES",B2="NAME MODIFICATION", B2="MULTIPLE VISA",B2="ADD PERSONNEL"),IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,WEEKDAY(A2)=1),A2+3, A2+5,
IF(OR(B2="LETTERS",B2="PRINT FROM JAWAZAT",B2="EXTENDED OF VISIT VISA",B2="INFORMATION MODIFICATION"),A2+1))))))

Comment: in that case, try removing the first comma after `A2+34`

Comment: still having the same message

Comment: if I removed the first comma  , then my nesting IF will not be in the "false" statement 

My nesting is in the false statement

Comment: I am really confused and missed up every thing 

can you please fix the code for me and type it 
pleaasssseeeeee

Comment: IF(OR(B2="PASSPORT LOST REPLACEMENT",B2="NATIONAL MDIFICATION"),A2+34,
IF(OR(B2="OCCUPATION CHANGE"),A2+21,
IF(OR(B2="IQAMA OF ISSUANCE",B2="IQAMAS RE-NEWAL",B2="LOST IQAMA REPLACEMENT",B2="TRANSFER OF SPONSORSHIP",B2="BUSINESS VISA R",B2="SEPARATION OF PERSONNEL"),A2+7,
IF(OR(B2="LETTERS FROM SISTER COMPANIES",B2="NAME MODIFICATION", B2="MULTIPLE VISA",B2="ADD PERSONNEL"),IF(OR(WEEKDAY(A2)=7,WEEKDAY(A2)=1),A2+3, A2+5,
IF(OR(B2="LETTERS",B2="PRINT FROM JAWAZAT",B2="EXTENDED OF VISIT VISA",B2="INFORMATION MODIFICATION"),A2+1))))))

I dont know what should I do 
can u fix it plz

Comment: My boss need it to be like this  

so  I'm really stuuck here with this problem 

can you please help me guysssssssssss